# PHP: eCommerce currency switching & Type juggling

Tags: php, casting, currency

I know you might say this question is doubled, But i really didn't find the real answer to my question.
If you don't want to read the details (**please jump down to THE POINT**) down..

I'm building a currency switcher option in my WebApp,so when the user changes the currency on the header from USD TO XYZ, the prices will be changed automatically, And I've done this already, but i wanted to change the symbol of the currency based on the active one, So i did it using PHP's type-juggling.

**THE POINT:**
Suppose this code:

```
$currency = "USD";
$real_price = 25;
$symbols = array ('USD' => '$ ',
                 'XYZ' => 'XyZ ');

$converted_price = currency_switcher($real_price, $currency);
// $converted_price will hold the converted amount assume its = 40
```

I added the currency-symbol to the number (type juggling):

```
$final_price = $symbols[$currency] . $converted_price;
echo $final_price; // Outputs:- $ 40
```

Now this is the only solution i came up with, However I read that it's considered as a bad practice.

The question is:
Is it really bad? and what other solutions I have?

**More outside the main point:**
I know that PHP have the [Internationalization Functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) Which is including [The NumberFormatter class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php)
But this is really seems to be very advanced to me, As i'm still new to PHP and the whole programming also.

I'm so sorry for this long story here. And I appreciate your time.

Comment: big mistake: storing your "formatted" currency values. that's just ... dumb. every time you have to do math with that currency, you have to UNDO the formatting. `1.34 + 2.34` is easy to do. `US$1.34 = $2.34CAD` is way more complicated. you store you currency values as plain numbers, always, and format to strings for output only. if you need to carry the currency type along, then define an object or an array, e.g. `$money = array('currency' => 'USD', value => '1.34')`

Comment: Yes I understand this point, Put i make this in my (UserCart - Class) as the last process before the output.
Actually its the last thing in the view method in my class.
So i did this after all the calculations (like the totals and the average and so..)